# Add environment parameter is Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I´m wondering if it´s possible to read an environment variable (Azure resource tag) from Azure Synapse Notebooks and Pipelines.

It would be useful since in many use cases the Azure resource names comprehend the environment name/code in it - i.e. they differ from environment to environment (dev, test, prod...). Reading the Azure resource environment tag within a Synapse pipeline or notebook would allow parametrizing the code, therefore making it more flexible and reusable.

Thanks in advance for any hint!

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing is probably a [Global Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/author-global-parameters) in Azure Data Factory (ADF).  Unfortunately these are not yet supported in Synapse pipelines but you can add your upvote for it here:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-azure-synapse-analytics/suggestions/42113842-using-global-parameters

It's also worth keeping an eye on the item status for updates - it *might* get changed to "Started" or "Complete" one day.  I have heard MS say the goal is to have as little difference as possible between ADF and Synapse pipelines so it's worth keeping an eye on.

The other method would probably be [Azure Key Vault integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-use-azure-key-vault-secrets-pipeline-activities) which is supported.  Create your secret, get the secret identifier and then use it in your pipeline.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply!

I was also taking Azure Key Vault into account. So far it´s probably the best option.

Answer (score 0):

if **username** is parameter in data factory, then find below code in python to read in synapse notebook.
python code :

```
name=f"{username}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Synapse does allow for 'custom parameters' but it does have this (much more manual to setup) option, which requires that you are setting up a CICD pipeline for Synapse
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/continuous-integration-delivery#create-custom-parameters-in-the-workspace-template

I definitely believe this will be available in Synapse Pipelines at some point like ADF; unfortunate that it isn't at this time
it is currently a feature idea that you can vote on
https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/eaa47674-0442-ec11-a819-000d3ae2b5ca

Answer (score 0):

Azure synapse notebook allow parameterizing and it can be changed in loops and default value can be overwritten. To create a parameter in notebook, you have to declare and assign them default value in a separate cell and then click on three dot on right top end of cell and select "Toggle Parameter Cell" to call the parameter you can use $param_name.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/synapse-notebook-activity?tabs=classical#passing-parameters)